# JavaScript array slice appears to clear out other array

Tags: javascript

First version of code

```js
// Creates random string
function randomString() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
}

// Creates dynamic rows for us
const rows = [...Array(16).keys()].map(el => {
  return {
    id: el + 1,
    title: `title-${randomString()}`,
    description: `description-${randomString()}`,
  };
});

// How mmany items per page
const limit = 10;

// Total number of pages that was determined by dividing the number of rows by the limit per page
const page_quantity = Math.ceil(rows.length / limit);

// Slice functionality
const pages = [];

// Array that will store rows for a page
const page = [];

rows.forEach((row, index) => {
  // Will determine we if we have reached the limit
  const is_page = (index + 1) % limit === 0;

  // Push rows to page
  page.push(row);

  // If we have reached the limit push "page" to the pages array
  if (is_page) {
    console.log(page);
    pages.push(page);
    page.splice(0)
  }

  // If we have not reached the limit per page but have reached the end of the array push page to pages
  if (index === rows.length - 1) {
    console.log(page);
    pages.push(page);
    page.splice(0)
  }

});

console.log(pages);
```

Results :

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)

(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)

(2) [Array(0), Array(0)]
0: []
1: []
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

If I change `page` to `let pages = []` and swap out `page.splice()` with `page = []` like so:

```js
// Creates random string
function randomString() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
}

// Creates dynamic rows for us
const rows = [...Array(7).keys()].map(el => {
  return {
    id: el + 1,
    title: `title-${randomString()}`,
    description: `description-${randomString()}`,
  };
});

// How mmany items per page
const limit = 10;

// Total number of pages that was determined by dividing the number of rows by the limit per page
const page_quantity = Math.ceil(rows.length / limit);

// Slice functionality
const pages = [];

// Array that will store rows for a page
let page = [];

rows.forEach((row, index) => {
  // Will determine we if we have reached the limit
  const is_page = (index + 1) % limit === 0;
  console.log((index + 1) % limit === 0);

  // Push rows to page
  page.push(row);

  // If we have reached the limit push "page" to the pages array
  if (is_page) {
    console.log(page);
    pages.push(page);
    page = [];
  }

  // If we have reached the end of the array push elements to page
  if (index === rows.length - 1) {
    pages.push(page);
    page = [];
  }

});

console.log(pages);
```

I get the correct results an array of two elements, one containing 10 "rows" and the other containing 6 "rows". Why is the first one not working with `Array.splice`?

Comment: You're using the same `page` array, and modifying it in place with `splice()`. All the elements of `pages` are that same array.

Comment: Remember, `pages.push(page)` doesn't make a copy of the `page` array. It just pushes a reference to the array.

Comment: Ahh, ok that makes sense "it pushes a reference". I was scratching my head. Where can I find this reference stuff on MDN?

Answer (score 0):

When you call Array.splice(0), a new array with all of the items from the original array is returned and the original array is set to []. When you push the original array you are pushing a pointer to the original array which you are emptying using the slice function.

It will work as you intended if you leave

```
const page = [];
```

but replace

```
pages.push(page);
page = [];
```

with

```
pages.push(page.splice(0));
```

Comment: So this is an issue with pointers/references when using `[]` or `{}`?

Comment: Not really. Using `const page` tells the js engine that `page` will always be a pointer to the same memory address. Using `let page` tells the js engine that you are going to use `page` to refer to something and that thing might change. Whether using `const` or `let`, when you call `page.splice(0)` you are changing the contents of the memory address that you have pushed onto `pages`. When you use `let` and you reassign `page` using `page = []`, you are telling the js engine that that `page` now points to a new place in memory, so the old `page` that you pushed onto `pages` is left as is.